# Correct config wal-e s3 for minio

Tags: postgresql, backup

Try run PostgreSQL + WAL-E + Minio.

Minio: https://github.com/minio/

```
yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
yum install -y postgresql96 postgresql96-server wal-e python-gevent lzop pv python34-pip
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
systemctl enable postgresql-9.6
systemctl start postgresql-9.6
mkdir -p /etc/wal-e.d/env
echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" > /etc/wal-e.d/env/AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" > /etc/wal-e.d/env/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
echo 's3://10.233.60.57:9000' >  /etc/wal-e.d/env/WALE_S3_ENDPOINT
echo 's3://minio/pg-backups' >  /etc/wal-e.d/env/WALE_S3_PREFIX
chown -R root:postgres /etc/wal-e.d
pip3 install envdir gevent boto
systemctl restart postgresql-9.6
sudo su - postgres
```

Minio configured as:

[image]

I create large ~1 GB random dataset in PostgreSQL
https://gist.github.com/ololobus/5b25c432f208d7eb31051a5f238dffff

But WAL don`t have in Minio.

Log WAL-E

```
envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env wal-e backup-push /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data
wal_e.main   INFO     MSG: starting WAL-E
        DETAIL: The subcommand is "backup-push".
        STRUCTURED: time=2019-02-12T07:41:01.239297-00 pid=18672
wal_e.operator.backup INFO     MSG: start upload postgres version metadata
        DETAIL: Uploading to s3://minio/pg-backups/basebackups_005/base_000000010000000000000092_00000040/extended_version.txt.
        STRUCTURED: time=2019-02-12T07:43:31.367410-00 pid=18672
wal_e.operator.backup WARNING  MSG: blocking on sending WAL segments
        DETAIL: The backup was not completed successfully, but we have to wait anyway.  See README: TODO about pg_cancel_backup
        STRUCTURED: time=2019-02-12T07:43:31.370409-00 pid=18672
NOTICE:  pg_stop_backup cleanup done, waiting for required WAL segments to be archived
```

Comment: What is Minio?  And what exactly is your question?  Are you sure WAL files are not being uploaded after you reach the state you've shown in the log?

Comment: Minio: https://github.com/minio/